# App crashes, but only on iOS 14, and only if installed via MDM

Tags: xcode, crash, ios14, mdm, xcode13

We're experiencing an extremely bizarre crash in our iOS/iPadOS app.

Some major changes in our latest release:

- Built with Xcode 13.0 on Big Sur 11.6
- Dropped support for iOS 13
- Updated Firebase to 8.9.1
- Built using the latest fastlane version

OK here's the bizarre part: our app works fine for users who download and install the app directly from the App Store or TestFlight on both iOS 14 & 15.

However, the app crashes on launch for iOS 14 users who get the app pushed to their phone by MDM from the App Store (public or private release, doesn't matter) and install it from a dialog box stating e.g. "AirWatch is about to install REDACTED from the App Store. Your iTunes account will not be charged for this app."

So what is the difference between launching the app after installing it yourself, and launching it after MDM installs it—in both cases, the app originates from the App Store?

Here is an example crash log:

```
{"app_name":"REDACTED","timestamp":"REDACTED","app_version":"REDACTED","slice_uuid":"REDACTED","adam_id":REDACTED,"build_version":"REDACTED","platform":0,"bundleID":"com.REDACTED.REDACTEDapp","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)","incident_id":"REDACTED","name":"REDACTED"}
Incident Identifier: REDACTED
CrashReporter Key:   REDACTED
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             REDACTED [1561]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/REDACTED/REDACTED.app/REDACTED
Identifier:          com.REDACTED.REDACTEDapp
Version:             REDACTED
AppStoreTools:       13A1030d
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.REDACTED.REDACTEDapp [562]


Date/Time:           2021-10-26 15:17:43.5707 -0500
Launch Time:         2021-10-26 15:17:43.1390 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.04.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000115596b28
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [1561]
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000016d11d5c0   x1: 0x0000000000000008   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016d11d590   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x736665727373616c   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x000000005f24901f   x9: 0x000000000f8884a0  x10: 0x000000000000901c  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000ff0006  x13: 0x000000000000c000  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0xffffffffffffffff
   x16: 0x00000001030879cc  x17: 0x6ae100016d11d440  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000115596b28
   x20: 0x000000016d11daf8  x21: 0x000000016d11dad0  x22: 0x0000000105d00000  x23: 0x000000000f896b28
   x24: 0x000000005f24901f  x25: 0x0000000105d0e680  x26: 0x000000000000e688  x27: 0x000000016d11db08
   x28: 0x0000000000001b99   fp: 0x000000016d11d6a0   lr: 0xba6bf2010306bf84
    sp: 0x000000016d11d620   pc: 0x000000010306beec cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x00000000  Address size fault

Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EOF
```

We don't see these crashes appearing in Crashlytics or Xcode organizer, and we never get a stack trace or useful error message.

I can reproduce the crash locally using our UEM test account for VMWare Workspace One (AirWatch), but it does not happen on AdHoc or Developer builds, nor does it happen if Xcode is connected with a live debugger session.

We tried regenerating all our provisioning profiles with DER encoding, then re-signing and re-submitting the app to Apple, but it did not help the problem. We also tried turning off LTO (link-time optimization) and rolling back Firebase to the version before we had this problem 7.11.

Note: we added logging to everywhere we could think of in the app, including AppDelegate init methods, but when it crashes on iOS 14 MDM installs, we get no log messages at all in the console (whereas when it launches on iOS 15 we get plenty of log messages and no crash).

Here's another example crash log. Sometimes we get the VMRegion info like this, sometimes we don't.

```
Incident Identifier: B5916B4C-5F24-43B4-B038-8F20B4CF60DE
CrashReporter Key:   a31b47951ef9c86f80d994b5128fd8f81060023a
Hardware Model:      iPad6,8
Process:             REDACTED [514]
Path:                /Volumes/VOLUME/*/REDACTED.app/REDACTED
Identifier:          com.REDACTED.REDACTEDapp
Version:             2021.0.58 (2021.44.0.433401)
AppStoreTools:       13A1030d
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.REDACTED.REDACTEDapp [307]

Date/Time:           2021-11-01 16:12:12.7748 -0700
Launch Time:         2021-11-01 16:12:12.4122 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.7.1 (18G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    10.80.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000011a3351c8
VM Region Info: 0x11a3351c8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 4553  Bytes before following region: 1395945016
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      VM_ALLOCATE              11a330000-11a334000 [   16K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  GAP OF 0x53348000 BYTES
      Stack Guard              16d67c000-16d680000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL; [11]
Terminating Process: exc handler [514]

Terminating Process: exc handler [514]
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EOF
```

Another example:

```
Incident Identifier: 7C56CCB2-79BC-4AF2-91C2-5CFC8A0ABBA6
CrashReporter Key:   a31b47951ef9c86f80d994b5128fd8f81060023a
Hardware Model:      iPad6,8
Process:             REDACTED MDM [27056]
Path:                /Volumes/VOLUME/*/REDACTED MDM.app/REDACTED MDM
Identifier:          com.REDACTED.REDACTEDappmdm
Version:             2021.0.63 (2021.46.5.000005)
AppStoreTools:       13A1030d
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.REDACTED.REDACTEDappmdm [1967]

Date/Time:           2021-11-11 17:22:03.7594 -0800
Launch Time:         2021-11-11 17:22:01.0685 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.7.1 (18G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    10.80.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000180000fa8
VM Region Info: 0x180000fa8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 4009  Bytes before following region: 685764696
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      VM_ALLOCATE              17fffc000-180000000 [   16K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  GAP OF 0x28e00000 BYTES
      unused shlib __TEXT      1a8e00000-1b0000000 [114.0M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ... this process
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL; [11]
Terminating Process: exc handler [27056]

Terminating Process: exc handler [27056]
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EOF
```

The only common thread seems to be that there's a VM_ALLOCATE that allocated a block of size 0x4000 bits. That's a pretty common size for a DATA segment so I don't think it's particularly useful information.

Update:

We've discovered that setting the deployment target back down to iOS 13 makes the problem not happen. It only happens when the deployment target is 14 or higher. Also, the crash happens before we even run a single line of code in our app, according to not seeing any os_log messages that we added to all the init methods in our UIApplication and UIApplicationDelegate classses and many static load methods.

Comment: have you tried it below ios 14? this seems to be a problem with your memory is overflowing.

Comment: We've discovered that setting the deployment target to iOS 13 makes the problem not happen. Also, the crash happens before we even run a single line of code in our app, based on putting log messages in a bunch of places and seeing what happens.

Comment: I am getting similar issue but on Testflight, pre-iOS 15, but it suddenly started happening and has nothing to do with a change in build target

Comment: Hey @daredevil1234 - is your issue similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316323/ios-app-crashes-at-launch-on-testflight-for-ios-14-and-below-but-not-ios-15 ?

Comment: Our issue did not seem to impact the TestFlight build, for what it's worth.

Comment: @ChIngalls i think so, i put my answer there for the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316323/ios-app-crashes-at-launch-on-testflight-for-ios-14-and-below-but-not-ios-15/70356479#70356479